# Javascript not working in safari 6.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, safari

I have some Iframes on my webpage in Safari 6.0.5 but the page does not load correctly. The HTML seems to be loading fine but the javascript code doesn't work. I am getting errors such as the follow:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://like-minded.us/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/n46r3KUHy-c. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

http://livepassdl.conviva.com/ver/2.72.0.13589/LivePass.jsFailed to load resource: cannot decode raw data

I am trying to figure out which is the main problem and also how to fix them. Any help is appreciated. Everything runs fine in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy

Comment: But my problem is in Safari :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the CDN I was using (CloudFlare) - I turned off both Rocket and JS minification and problem solved!